# How can I convert a list of hex colors (or RGB, sRGB) stored in a text file into an Image

Tags: python, imagemagick, processing

I have a list of approx. 1000 hex colors which I would like to convert into an image with (e.g. a grid of squares or rectangles) filled with these colors. Is there an easy way to achieve this in Imagemagick (or any other software: e.g. Processing/Python).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `bash` and `ImageMagick` like this:

```
while read h; do convert xc:"$h" miff:- ; done < colours | montage -geometry +0+0 miff:- result.png
```

So, if your file `colours` looks like this:

```
#000000
#ffffff
#ff0000
#00ff00
#0000ff
pink
yellow
navy
rgb(128,128,128)
rgb(64,64,64)
rgb(200,200,200)
```

you will get this:

[image]

If you want the squares bigger than their current size of 1x1, just change the `convert` command to specify the size of the square, to say 10x10:

```
while read h; do 
   convert -size 10x10 xc:"$h" miff:- 
done < colours | montage -geometry +0+0 miff:- result.png
```

Comment: You are a true master. That is exactly what I wanted and everything in a one liner. Thanks a million, very much appreciated !

Comment: Excellent! Pleased to be of service. By the way, if you know you want, say 32 tiles across the width and the height to then be determined by the number of squares, you can use `montage -tile 32x ...`. Likewise if you want a specific number of tiles down the page, say 20 and the width to vary with the number of lines in your `colours` file, you can use `montage -tile x20 ...`

Comment: Cool thanks again ! I wonder if I can sort the colors before printing them, so similar colors are close to each other. This script is very useful. Thanks again.

Comment: You can do that sort of thing - see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34808744/2836621 You would pass the image from this answer as the input image to the linked answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell is it possible to add the name of the color into the box? I am using names from the showrgb command. I tried using label and caption, the text shows up but everything turns black and white

Answer (score 0):

Code is in python
You can use the following steps:

1. convert your list to numpy array

```
    import numpy as np 

    myarray = np.asarray(mylist)
```

2. Use scipy to save the numpy array you have just created

```
    from scipy.misc import toimage

    rgb = scipy.misc.toimage(myarray)

    toimage(rgb).show()
```

Note: Scipy requres PIL to be installed pre-hand.

Another Solution without Scipy is as follows, but you need to modify according to your needs. you will need PIL here:

```
import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((500,500))

#Rescale to 0-255 and convert to uint8
rescaled = (255.0 / data.max() * (data - data.min())).astype(np.uint8)

im = Image.fromarray(rescaled)
im.save('testing.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with the [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) tag, so here is the Processing solution:

**Step 1:** Load the file. You can use the `loadStrings()` functions for this. This gives you an array of `String` values, which in your case will hold your hex values. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html).

**Step 2:** Loop through those hex values. Use a regular `for` loop or an enhanced `for` loop.

**Step 3:** Convert each hex `String` into an `int` color using the `unhex()` function. This gives you an `int` that can be passed into any color function, such as `fill()`. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/unhex_.html).

**Step 4:** Use those colors to draw your image. You haven't said how the lines in the file map to a coordinate on-screen, so you'll have to do that mapping. Then just change the fill color and draw a rectangle at that coordinate.

It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions other than to point you to [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) and tell you to break your problem down into smaller steps and just try something. Then if you get stuck on one of those specific steps, you can ask a more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question, which is more what Stack Overflow was designed for. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know why a concise question like this is voted down. The rational of why this happens is so random and it would be great that if someone makes the effort of voting something down, that he/she has to explain why. Otherwise nobody learns anything from this experience.

Comment: @user413734 See the bottom of my answer for an explanation of why you're getting downvotes. Long story short: this question is **not** concise. I'm happy to answer in general terms, but that really isn't what Stack Overflow was built for.